# What is the correct term for a method whose only purpose is to call another method?

Tags: java, function, methods, terminology

Occasionally there will be a method that calls another method and does nothing else. I'll demonstrate with an example:

```
void foo() {
    bar();
}
void bar() {
    // do some actual work
}
```

Is there some precise terminology that could be used to describe method `foo`? I've sometimes seen these called "bridge" methods, but I know this to be incorrect, since a "bridge method" has a separate, well-defined meaning. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: wasteful and redundant?

Comment: I would call it a PROXY method ... and if its only purpose is to call another method then I would call it a DUMB method.

Comment: I guess it may be pattern if you are intentionally applying a design pattern e.g. adapter pattern might adapt one method onto another (your example does not provide enough detail to know if this is true in your case).

I guess you often do this kind of thing to expose a public API which internally calls a private API e.g. if you're overloading methods on the public API, but implementing with a private API.

Comment: it's hard to tell from a foo-bar example.

Comment: A bureaucratic method....................

Comment: @Cybernate, proxies actually do some other stuff like switching context and/or bridging calls between different layers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a [Wrapper Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function).

Contrary to @scrappedcola's comment, a wrapper function is not necessarily wasteful and redundant. An instance may satisfy an interface, or forward a call.

Comment: That's the term we are looking for +1

Comment: *An instance may satisfy an interface....* heavily contradicts: *method whose only purpose is to call another method?*, otherwise 1st and foremost it does impl. the interface contract.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a simple [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern)